# Как добавить атрибут defer всем скриптам при загрузке страницы

Tags: javascript

Нужно добавить атрибут `defer` при загрузке страницы всем `<script>`-ам. Таким образом хочу ускорить загрузку страницы.

Данный скрипт не срабатывает:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute("defer", "defer");
```

Как это сделать правильно?

Comment: А зачем вы создаёте новый скрипт, если вы хотите добавить атрибут ко всем уже имеющимся?

Comment: @Grundy есть идеи как добавить атрибут скриптам, которые ещё не обработаны? Или всё ж таки ответ - "никак"?

Comment: @Regent, вообще _никак_, так как, когда есть доступ к тегу script - он уже загружается и добавление или удаление атрибута ни на что не повлияет. Но можно вставлять их на страницу динамически, например, как это делает requirejs. Передавать загрузчику список адресов, и для них создавать свои элементы script с нужными атрибутами

Comment: @Grundy я уповал на то, что, возможно, есть какой-то хитрый и не совсем законный способ получить в скрипте весь текст страницы до его парсинга браузером. Варианты `document.getElementsByTagName('script')` и `document.scripts` бессмысленны в данной ситуации - это понятно. Вставлять скрипты динамически - это да, но автору вот зачем-то нужно сделать именно так. В общем, можно тогда официально заключить, что ответ - "никак". И добавить такой ответ как альтернатива трём имеющимся неправильным.

Comment: @Regent, не, такого [способа нет](http://plnkr.co/edit/fWdZC9tVL8mDaujpckWF?p=preview) :-) если только браузреное расширение, которое будет перехватывать все

Comment: @Regent я использую cms joomla , установленные расширения(модули, плагины) сами подключают в <head> скрипты и стили, поэтому думал сделать именно так)

Comment: @SerhiyBilik понятно. В общем, если в настройках расширений нет возможности повлиять на способ загрузки скриптов, то всё печально. Принимать или не принимать ответ - право ваше, но вот, считайте, два человека вам говорят что никак.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Никак**.

Проблема в том, что и `document.scripts`, и `document.getElementsByTagName('script')` вернут только те скрипты, что уже появились в DOM. То есть те, которые уже выполнены, если у них изначально не было `async` и `defer`.

Соответственно, если поставить скрипт, добавляющий атрибут, первым в списке скриптов, то он не увидит других скриптов. Если поставить последним - то остальные скрипты к моменту запуска скрипты уже будут выполнены.

Попытка "пуститься во все тяжкие" и поменять `document.documentElement.innerHTML` ничем хорошим не кончится, хотя бы той же самой причине: остальных скриптов опять-таки ещё не будет в `innerHTML`.

---

Можно попытаться провернуть это через плагин к браузеру, но [поговаривают](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10076783/3432401), что и это не особо перспективный вариант.

Answer (score 1):

```
   [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('script')).forEach(function (script) {
      script.setAttribute("defer", "defer");
   })
```

Comment: Как по вашему, сможет jQ само себе проставить аттрибут defer **до** того, как загрузится?

Comment: И дело не только в проставлении `defer`у _jquery.js_. Проблема ещё и в том, что если этот код разместить до скриптов, то в `$("script")` будет 0 элементов. А если после скриптов, то скрипты уже будут прогружены без `defer`.

Comment: Ок, 
[].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('script')).forEach(function(script){ script.setAttribute("defer", "defer"); })

Comment: Но это вы исправили только проблему, озвученную @Darth. А что насчет проблемы, озвученной мною?

Answer (score 0):

```
for(let script of document.scripts) script.setAttribute('defer', 'defer')
```

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, в `document.scripts` находятся только уже прогруженные скрипты. То есть толка от добавления атрибута им ровным счетом 0.

Answer (score 0):

Я так понял задача выдать всем скриптам на странице `defer` ? вот пример на jquery

```
var arr = $("script");
for (var i=0;i < arr.length;i++) {
    $(arr[i]).attr("defer","defer");
}
```

Comment: Как по вашему, сможет jQ само себе проставить аттрибут defer **до** того, как загрузится?

Comment: И дело не только в проставлении `defer`у _jquery.js_. Проблема ещё и в том, что если этот код разместить до скриптов, то в `$("script")` будет 0 элементов. А если после скриптов, то скрипты уже будут прогружены без `defer`.

Comment: Тогда задача сама для себя парадокс "написать скрипт который должен выполниться и выдать сам себе defer который выполнит его позже" ...  извините ЧТО ?

Comment: При чем тут "сам себе `defer`"? Сам себе скрипт ставить `defer` не должен - это понятно. Вы понимаете, что ваш скрипт можно будет выполнить только после того, как прогрузится _jquery.js_?

Comment: Да , а вы понимаете что нужно написать скрипт который должен заставить всех скрипты "подождать" ? Эта формулировка вам не кажется странной ? Я понимаю что можно написать без jquery , что бы той же jquery дать defer

Comment: Мне вообще кажется, что ответом на вопрос, заданный автором, является "никак", Но вы же предлагаете решение. И если оно очевидно некорректное, то чего вы спорите-то? Минусы вполне заслужены - ответ же неверный. Если вам вопрос кажется странным, и ответа на него вы не знаете, то зачем вы размещаете псведо-ответ?

Comment: "никак" согласен . А то как я понял , так и ответил , это написано в моем первом предложении , ведь не в этом смысл , давать ответы , пускай даже на на очень конкретные вопросы .

Comment: В такой формулировке как в ответе - да. Но всё же в вопросе четко даётся понять, что проставлять нужно до прогрузки скриптов, чтобы они сразу грузились в фоне. Наверняка знает только автор вопроса, но пока что всё идёт именно к такому варианту. Ну и я пока что жду какого-нибудь хитрого корректного решения.